# Render/display json file to html via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

how to display this json file using jquery?

```
[ { "code":"00-002159", "lastname":"SALUNGA", "firstname":"JEFFERSON" },
  { "code":"00-002160", "lastname":"TUMANAN", "firstname":"RHODA" } ]
```

and look like this

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>code</th>   <th>lastname</th>          <th>firstname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>00-002159</td>     <td>SALUNGA </td>          <td>JEFFERSON</td>
<td>00-002160 </td>    <td>TUMANAN </td>          <td>RHODA</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have to loop through the object and use some html to display thats it.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery.template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) should be a good approach to show the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var data = [ { "code":"00-002159", "lastname":"SALUNGA", "firstname":"JEFFERSON" }, { "code":"00-002160", "lastname":"TUMANAN", "firstname":"RHODA" } ];
var string = "";
   $.each(data, function() {
      $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        v += " ";
        string += v;
      });
    });
    alert(string);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse json data, the data what you mention in example is array of objects

```
var data = [ { "code":"00-002159", "lastname":"SALUNGA", "firstname":"JEFFERSON" },
             { "code":"00-002160", "lastname":"TUMANAN", "firstname":"RHODA" } ]
```

`[] - Represents js array` an `{} - Represents js Object` So to parse data and get RHODA use `data[0].firstname;`

Answer (score 0):

see this link also very useful

[Loop through JSON object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800593/loop-through-json-object-list)

I didn't format the string properly , please check that

Assume your json has this format

```
[ { "code":"00-002159", "lastname":"SALUNGA", "firstname":"JEFFERSON" }, { "code":"00-002160", "lastname":"TUMANAN", "firstname":"RHODA" } ]
```

Assume you have response in a codes object

```
var finalHtml='';

finalHtml='<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>code</th>   <th>lastname</th>          <th>firstname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>'
    for(i=0; i< codes.length;i++)
    {

       //store the values and paint the html
       finalHtml+=<td>0codes[i].code;</td>     <td>codes[i].lastname </td>          <td>JEFFERSON</td>;      
    }
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>'
```

append to the dom finally

have some container and do

```
$('#containerID').html(finalHtml);
```