# Object to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a object like this one. How can i convert it to Array in JavaScript.

I'm try so hard, but it doesn't work, i can not alert or console.log it.

I have this object below

```
{
    "2017": {
        "08": [{
            "id": "22",
            "pass": "temp1"
        }, {
            "id": "23",
            "pass": "af",
        }],

        "09": [{
            "id": "25",
            "pass": "zx"

        }]
    },

    "2018": {
        "08": [{
            "id": "24",
            "pass": "gre"
        }]
    }
}
```

And this is the array i want it to be in JavaScript

```
Array
(
    [2017] => Array
        (
            [08] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22
                            [pass] => temp1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [pass] => af
                        )

                )

            [09] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 25
                            [pass] => zx

                        )

                )

        )

    [2018] => Array
        (
            [08] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [pass] => gre
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Thank you very much for answering

Comment: What is your desired array?

Comment: Like the object but i want to have a key to loop it

Comment: You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: can you make an example for me, i'm just start to program on javascript

Comment: Update the question with your desired array, then it would be easier for other user to solve the problem

Comment: I use PHP to "json_encode" it

Comment: But what should your array look like?

Comment: Show us how would you like the array to look like. Like: I have THIS, and I want it to be THAT

Comment: Just update the question

Comment: That's the correct representation of the array in Javascript. PHP doesn't distinguish between associative and indexed arrays, JS does - assoc arrays are objects. What *exactly* do you want to do with the object? if you simply want to loop through it, you can use the `for..in` loop, see  Sebastian's answer.

Comment: I want to alert loop to alert id and pass althought i don't know the key 2017 2018 and 08 09

Comment: The array you posted is PHP associative array. Which in JavaScript is represented as Object which you already have. See my answer to know how to iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

For the very first, I would like to tell you that this isn't a mere JavaScript object, it's a list of JSON objects.

Get this list in some variable and then use it like given in below link.

[Loop through JSON object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800593/loop-through-json-object-list)

Comment: But it is a JS object.

Comment: You're right. This is a object, but concern is, what the object contains. It contains a list of objects.

Comment: As per the code snippet in question, the JS object contains a JSON list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscore.js to do this:

```
_(obj).each(function(elem, key){
   arr.push(elem[0]);
});
```

Comment: Why underscore.js? There is easy pure JS solution for this. There is no need to load any library for that

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to achieve is to loop through the object you don't have to convert it to an array. In JavaScript, there is `for...in` loop which will be perfect in this case. Use it like this:

```
var myobj = {
    key1: "val1",
    key2: "val2",
    key3: "val3",
}

for(var key in myobj){
    var value = myobj[key];

    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to read more about `for...in` loop